# Azure web app performance within Corporate network poor vs Internet

Tags: performance, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web application and hosted in MS Azure PaaS (Azure West Datacenter). User can only access application via Internet. My Client using his corporate network (their proxy server is in Copenhagen & the users are in NL) experience performance issues while accessing the Web application. Users connected via internet have much better performance as they connect to internet directly bypassing Corporate infrastructure.

My Corporate network team did an analysis and found that there is no performance delay when accessing the Web app.
1. They did a CMD : ping  to the proxy address to check the response 
2. They captured the results with Application Insights – BrowserTimings and found it satisfactory.

Now my manager asks if we can identify the performance using the Azure Application Insights. I tried accessing the Analytics feature in Azure Application Insights using below query:

```
requests 
| where user_AuthenticatedId  == "emailaddress"
```

But I couldn't identify any differences. I know which user access via corporate network and I pass their email address to check the performance Bucket

Is there any other way we can check the network performance in Azure Application Insights?

I also want to try and check with the network latency test via [PSPing tool](http://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/PsPing).  I got the outbound IP address (there was 5 address) of the Azure Web App and tried pinging from internet but I receive Request Timeout error. Then I saw recently they have enabled SSL to my azure web app. Does that make any difference?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any other way we can check the network performance in Azure Application Insights?

Yes, by adding a new chart. We will see the client metrics in the Chart details panel. You could check the client metrics which you want to monitor.

[image]

Following are the detail description of these client metrics.

1. Browser page load time: Browser page load time, client processing time, page load network connect time.
2. Client processing time: Time between receiving the last byte of a document until the DOM is loaded. Async requests may still be processing.
3. Page load network connect time: Time between user request and network connection. Includes DNS lookup and transport connection.
4. Receiving response time： Time between the first and last bytes, or until disconnection.
5. Send request time: Time between network connection and receiving the first byte.